# ApplyWebConfigModifications to only one web application and not all the farm

Tags: sharepoint

I want to apply web.config modifications only on the webapplication i am installing my feature on and not all the web.configs of the farm. i am using SPWebService.ApplyWebConfigModifications , how can i do that? Help pls

Answer (score 2):

The feature you use to deploy the modifications should be web app scoped and should have a feature receiver, activating the feature on the desired web app only should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
{
    using (SPSite site = ((SPSite)properties.Feature.Parent))
    {
        SPWebApplication webApplication = site.WebApplication;
        // webApplication.WebConfigModifications.Clear();
        // do modifications, using the feature.GetType().FullName as the Owner

        webApplication.Update();
        webApplication.Farm.Services.GetValue<SPWebService>().ApplyWebConfigModifications();
    }
}

public override void FeatureDeactivating(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
{
    using (SPSite site = ((SPSite)properties.Feature.Parent))
    {
        SPWebApplication webApplication = site.WebApplication;
        Collection<SPWebConfigModification> entries = webApplication.WebConfigModifications;

        for (int i = entries.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            SPWebConfigModification entry = entries[i];
            if (entry.Owner == this.GetType().FullName)
                entries.Remove(entry);

        }

        webApplication.Update();
        webApplication.Farm.Services.GetValue<SPWebService>().ApplyWebConfigModifications();
    }
}
```

**Edit**

In order to manage your current modifications without going directly in the SQL Server, use [this file](http://www.dynasign.nl/downloads/webconfig.aspx) and copy it inside the folder: 
**C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\12\TEMPLATE\ADMIN** and access it from **http://*centraladministration:PORT*/_admin/webconfig.aspx**

Original sources [TheKid blog](http://blog.thekid.me.uk/archive/2007/03/24/web-config-modification-manager-for-sharepoint.aspx) and [Harmjan Greving’s Blog](http://www.dynasign.nl/blog/?p=14)

Comment: ok, i used the above, the main problem is that my feature was scoped "farm", and on featureactivated a new line was added to web.config. Now everytime i install any feature, this line is always added to the web.config. I completely removed the feature, i even made a completely new feature with a new featureid (web app scoped) and still everytime i activate a feature, the same old line of the old (deleted) farm feature is added to all the web.configs.

This is crazy, how to cancel this thing, plsssss help.

Comment: When you add a WebConfigModification is lives in the Content Database, you need to use the WebConfig Modifications 'manager' created by Vincent Rothwell, I'll edit my post to reflect the new info.